# Android TODO app that syncs with others

Tags: gratis, android, synchronization, todo

I want to share TODO lists with other members of my team. So I need not only a TODO app that can sync my account on all my devices but sync also with others.

- We all use Android devices
- The app should be simple to handle
- Preferable free or at least cheap

Comment: Not using any – but while waiting for good recommendations, be welcome to take a look at my corresponding app listing: [Todo Apps with Synchronisation](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo#group_22). If you find a perfect match, you can of course also [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [TickTick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ticktick.task).

It is a simple TODO app which can sync between members of a list. It is also free for a 2-user setup. You need to go premium if you need more than 2 users on a single list.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep) might be also suitable, you can add others as contributors with Google account to several notes (they can be simple notes, check lists, etc). It synchronises as simple as Gmail or any other Google app.
The only downside is that all of you have to have a Google account.